# Asp fileupload ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on photo delete

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have an `asp:fileupload` control that stores an image in a database. When I select a file and then delete it, I get a ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error code, but doesn't throw an exception. I was wondering how I would be able to handle this error

Comment: This appears to only be a chrome issue. I have <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx"></customErrors> which works on IE...firefox won't allow a photo to be deleted while in use

Answer (score 0):

it could be handle if we set onclickclient event on file upload button as

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return handleUploading();" ID="UploadButton" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

here is javascript function

```js
        function handleUploading() {
          
            var fileUpload = $('#contRMSMaster_FileUploadControl');

            if (fileUpload.val() == '') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (fileUpload[0].files[0].size > 0) {
                  
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('file not found !');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```